# float128 in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any paper or research concerning float128 arithmetics applied to linear algebra problems(e.g. iterative solvers, decompositions etc.)?
How much benefit is really there in comparison with double? 
How much slower is it?

I've discovered this toolbox: http://www.advanpix.com/
Unfortunately it is commercial, but results if they are true, look impressive.

Comment: As far as I know, you would need an application with horrible conditioning to warrant the use of float128. I'm not sure if that helped.....

Comment: I guess any matrix that has condition number close to $\epsilon^{-1}$, where $\epsilon$ is the smallest significant floating point number can be better treated using more precise arithmetics.

Comment: [Here](http://www.advanpix.com/2011/10/12/multiprecision-computation-eigenvalues-eigenvectors/), one could use `sym()` when declaring the matrix and have any precision but it is *horribly* slow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quad-precision type `__float128` is available in PETSc. Since most sparse linear algebra methods are limited by memory bandwidth instead of floating point performance, it is often only about half the speed of double precision. It is especially useful when using matrix-free finite differencing (frequently used with Jacobian-free Newton-Krylov methods) or exploring whether a nearly-singular operator is actually singular. For most problems, it is possible and preferable to use a well-scaled and conditioning-friendly discretization so that quad precision is not necessary for production runs.

Comment: *"exploring whether a nearly-singular operator is actually singular"* :: Where would that happen?

Comment: How about degradation of convergence for iterative due to rounding off errors? For instance, trivial CG and loosing of conjugacy during solution can be less significant for float128.

Comment: @Nunoxic A common case is when your boundary conditions are not compatible (e.g. incorrect outflow conditions in the hyperbolic limit) or do not constrain a null space (too few points of contact in elasticity). Another is if you are trying to solve a steady-state problem that does not have a steady state or in which you find a local minimum. The inherent ill-conditioning could come from large jumps in material coefficients or very thin structures.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, that is true. It's actually common in engineering applications to use CG with full orthogonalization for that reason. Switching to quad precision saves memory and time (if you do enough iterations) by allowing the standard CG recurrence to be used.

Comment: @JedBrown, is there any comparison about that? How significant is this effect?

Comment: It's strongly dependent on the relative cost of applying the operator and preconditioner versus the cost of orthogonalization. Why are you curious? Pretty much any time there is a performance trade-off, you can select an example where it makes a big difference and an example where it's irrelevant. By choosing a nasty problem with an inexpensive operator and a poor preconditioner (so that many iterations are required), you can make full orthogonalization as expensive as you like relative to standard CG. It's much harder to show that you made good algorithmic choices to end up in that scenario.